# PHP: cutting a string in a number of characters blocks

Tags: php, count, split, character

I have a variable called $data which contains a giant string (27338 characters).

This string will be the content of a pdf file.

I need to add a footnote at the end of each page of the pdf file.

I’ve calculated 2642 characters per page.

How can I cut $data in chunks of 2642 characters so I can add the footnotes?

I'm trying:

```
$split = preg_split('/(.{0,2642})\s/',
                    $data,
                    0,
                    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$count = count($split);
foreach ($split as $key => $page) {

    echo $page; echo "<br><br>";
}
```

But each $page shows much less than 2642 characters.

Thanks a lot

Comment: this doesn't match a line break, does it? so you can set the dotall modifier like so: `/(.{0,2642})\s/s`

Comment: "I need to add a footnote at the end of each page of the pdf file." - counting letters will get you nowhere, as a PDF includes markup. To find the end of a page in a PDF you have to render the document. You need to use a PDF library to edit it properly, which probably lets you add footers anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used it with very large amount of data but a way to split strings in elements of equal length is to use the str_split function (see http://php.net/str_split)

usage:

```
$array = str_split('some text', 2);
```

and you will get an array with elements of length 2 (except for the last one)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring-function, which will create a specific substring (of a defined length) from a different string.

```
substr($STRING, A, B); //where $string is the original string, 
                       //A is the position where to start cutting
                       //B is how long the newly created string should be (it's optional!)
$text = "ABCDEF";
echo substr($text, 2, 2); //will give you "CD"
```

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
define("CHUNK_SIZE",2642);
$string = "big..";
$chunks = array();
for($x=0,$sz=strlen($string);$x<$sz;$x+=CHUNK_SIZE) {
   $chunks[] = substr($string,$x,$x+CHUNK_SIZE);
}
$chunks[0..n] += FOOTNOTE
```

then:

```
implode("",$chunks);
```

Comment: If you use that magical number, you should only assign it once above its usage. It is very likely to be 1. forgotten what the number represents and 2. very prone to errors. `CHARACTERS_PER_PAGE = 2642`

Comment: yes, a defin('CHARACTERS_PER_PAGE',2642); would be more appropriate, tx.